# Изменение значений полей по вызову события

Tags: javascript

Есть такой `HTML`:

```
<div>
    <span id="product1_price">1</span>
    <input class="number" value="1" />
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>

</div>

<div>
    <span id="product2_price">2</span>
    <input class="number" value="1" />
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>

</div>

<div>
    <span id="product3_price">3</span>
    <input class="number" value="1" />
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>

</div>

<div>
    <span id="product4_price">4</span>
    <input class="number" value="1" />
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>

</div>
```

Поля `span`-ов меняются по клику на `+`, но при этом поля `input`-ов должны так же менять значение. Делать ли это в том же цикле, что и в обработчике события клика по `+`, или в другом?

`js` для кликов по `+`:

```
plus = document.querySelectorAll('div.basket_plus');
for (var i=0; i<plus.length; i++) {
    plus[i].addEventListener( 'click', function(event) {
        var parent = event.target.parentNode, 
        span = parent.getElementsByTagName('span')[0],
        sum = span.innerHTML;
        span.innerHTML = parseInt(sum) + 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: так как выбирать придется разные элементы с разными классами - в одном цикле не получится

Comment: цикл просто вешает обработчики событий, соответственно можете делать тут  же

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, тогда я наверное не понял что спросили :-)

Comment: @Grundy, или я )))

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer, скорее все же я, как я сейчас думаю - автор хочет вместо `+ 1` делать `+ число из инпута`.

Comment: если добавить в цикл input = parent.getElementsByTagName('input')[0] 
а потом вывести через консоль , тогда выбирается нужный элемент инпута, но в таком случае когда делаем доп. инструкции 
var count =1 ;
input.value = count++;
собственно ничего не происходит

Comment: да, при нажатии на "+" в поле инпут должно так же меняться значение

Comment: @ddeadlink, стоп. я запутался, вы хотите по одному клику менять и sum и count?

Comment: вы хотите в инпут поместить тоже самое число что и в спан?

Comment: да, по 1 клику меняется и спан и инпут 
нажимаем + , меняет значение спан, а так же меняется значение поля инпут ,

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всю обработку делать в одном месте. Написать ф-ю обработчик клика, в которой менять всё, что нужно, и ловить клики.

Базовую цену единицы товара пропишем в атрибуте `data-unitprice`, чтобы пересчитывать цену при изменении кол-ва товара.

Ещё надо слушать события изменения в поле `<input>` – с ним та же история, что и с кликом по плюсу, только не надо инкрементировать собственное значение - оно уже.

```js
// ф-я обработчик события клика
function _click(e) {
  var parent = e.target.parentNode, // div товара
      span = parent.querySelector('span'),
      basePrice = span.dataset.unitprice,
      newPrice = basePrice * (++parent.querySelector('input').value)
  ;
  span.innerHTML = newPrice;
}

// ф-я обработчик события изменения поля ввода кол-ва
function _change(e) { // TODO: не давать количеству уехать в минус!
  var parent = e.target.parentNode, // div товара
      span = parent.querySelector('span'),
      basePrice = span.dataset.unitprice,
      newPrice = basePrice * parent.querySelector('input').value
  ;
  span.innerHTML = newPrice;
}

var i;

// слушать события у всех плюсов
var pluses = document.getElementsByClassName('basket_plus');
for(i=0; i<pluses.length; i++) pluses[i].addEventListener('click', _click);

// слушать события у всех input'ов 
var ins = document.getElementsByClassName('number'); // все плюсы
for(i=0; i<ins.length; i++) ins[i].addEventListener('change', _change);
```

```html
<div>
    <span id="product1_price" data-unitprice="11">11</span>
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
    <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
    <span id="product2_price" data-unitprice="22">22</span>
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
    <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
    <span id="product3_price" data-unitprice="33">33</span>
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
    <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
</div>
<div>
    <span id="product4_price" data-unitprice="44">44</span>
    <div class="basket_plus"> + </div>
    <input type="number" class="number" value="1" />
</div>
```

Comment: вариант отличный , но в таком случае изменение data-unitprice в случае ручного изменения значения инпут будет меняться только после следующего клика на +

Comment: Атрибут `data-unitprice` не меняется – это базовая цена одной единицы товара.  Обновил ответ – добавил обработчик изменения содержания поля ввода кол-ва.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я все же б событие change на input менял - красивее получается )

Comment: Рад, что вы знаете.  Событие `input` – часть HTML5. А вдруг вы старый IE захотите поддерживать? : )

Comment: в ввиду последних событий по поддержке IE, не думаю)